# Counting non-NULL values in R

Tags: r

I have a table:

| Account role | Created date | Deleted date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Manager | 2021-01-01 | 2021-04-05 |
| Administrator | 2021-01-12 | NULL |
| User | 2021-01-21 | NULL |
| User | 2021-02-12 | 2021-05-12 |
| Manager | 2021-02-15 | NULL |

I need to count non-NULL values grouped by Account roles. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are those string "NULL" or `NA` values ? It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(`Account role`) %>% 
  filter(`Deleted date` != "NULL") %>% 
  count()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `table()` function.
`table(df$Accountrole)`, should give the grouped counts. Also, with a

```r
sum(is.na(df$AccountRole))
```

you can learn the total number of `NA`'s in the column.

Comment: This would be a good answerif the values that say NULL are really NA.  But we don't actually know that -- which is why the other answers have assumed that thy are actually charactervaluses "NULL".  The table part is a good suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

Also with dplyr, you could use summarise()/summarize()

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(`Account role`) %>% 
   summarise(value = sum(is.null(`Deleted date`)),
             .groups="drop")
```

Comment: You still need the grouping by `Account role`s. :-)

Comment: First you would need to convert the "Null" values to NA.  alternatively you could say sum(`Deleted date` == "NULL").